# Sign in/up Modal in Angular2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have signup & login components which are able to be accessed through /#/signup and /#/login. I am trying to accomplish a 'content lock' similar to Quora where the user is prompted to login & signup.

The user enters my site, and can access many routes "for free," like #/home, #/contactus, etc. However, when the user tries to access #/secret, they could 'access' the page, but they are blocked from interacting with the page unless they are logged in.

Login Component (TS):

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  form: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  failureMessage: string;

  constructor(public appService: AppService,
              public fb: FormBuilder,
              public _authService: AuthService,
              public router: Router) {
    appService.getState().topnavTitle = 'Sign In';
    appService.getState().pageFullscreen = true;

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(6),
          Validators.maxLength(20)]]
    });
  }


  login(data: Object) {
    this.loading = true;
    this._authService.login(data).subscribe(res => {
      if (res === true) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      } else {
        this.failureMessage = 'Your username or password is incorrect.';
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Login HTML template:

```
<div class="sign-container">
  <div class="sign-background"></div>
  <md-card class="sign-card">
    <md-card-title><img style="height: 64px;" src="assets/img/logo-full.svg"></md-card-title>
    <md-card-subtitle>Sign in to continue.</md-card-subtitle>
    <br>
    <md-card-content>
      <ng-container *ngIf="failureMessage">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <strong>Error:</strong>
          {{failureMessage }}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
          [form inputs here]
      </form>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-actions>
      <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="login(form.value)"
      [disabled]="form.status === 'INVALID' || loading ">LOGIN</button>
    </md-card-actions>
    <br>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active">Sign Up</a></p>
  </md-card>

</div>
```

How can I create a modal which can contain the sign in form, and allow for the component to switch to sign up in the modal? Additionally, when the sign in is successful, the modal can close.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/KhTilp27hmIDZpawJXM3 (Work in Progress)

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: @Aravind can you recommend what would you like in the plunkr?

Comment: if you create a working prototype we can help fixing using that

Comment: @Aravind I'm on it, give me a few to get it set up

Comment: Ok . take your time notify me once done. if needed you can reach in fb @ aravind2109

Comment: it's not quite working, but I migrated my code to plunkr, maybe you can assist.. @aravind also send you fb req

Comment: What's the reason behind "locking" the entire site? Surely that will just annoying the living hell out of people? Or am I missing the point here? :D

Comment: @Chrillewoodz the entire site isnt locked. I am trying to implement a conditional login/signup modal based on the current route i.e. '/secret/